# Listbox Count error

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm receiving an error on the 5th line, listCell.**Count**() tried resolving it with listCell.Items.Count() but that didn't work... any idea? error: does not contain a definition for count.

```
        int listCellCounter = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < listId.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("something " + listId.Items[x] + " " + listCell.Items[listCellCounter]);
            if (listCellCounter == listCell.Count() - 1)
            {
                listCellCounter = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                listCellCounter += 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `listCell` implements `IEnumerable`, then the extension method `Count()` will work if the `using System.Linq` is added (assuming .NET 3.5 or more is used).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not quite sure what collection the listCell is but I'd imagine that .Count() should be a property. So try to change your code to this:

```
    ...

    if (listCellCounter == listCell.Count - 1) // or listCell.Items.Count - 1
    { 
        listCellCounter = 0;
    }

    ...
```

The error you are getting basicly just means that there is no Count() method in listCell.